# SSO OAuth2 Workflow

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm currently working on a PHP WebApp which we decided to split up in order to avoid becoming a monolith. In order to improve user experience we'd like to use an OAuth2 Server for SSO: So the user only needs to login once and has access to all apps.

In order to get going I've read the [OAuth Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and I hope that I got the basic concept (I decided to go for the authorizationCode grant type).

So let's say I have one app running on

> webapp1.somedomain.com

and I have an OAuth Server on

> oauth.somedomain.com

If a user tries to access **webapp1.somedomain.com**:

- He will will be redirected to **oauth.somedomain.com** including client id, redirect url, response type and state (optional) as query parameters
- After logging in with his credentials, the user will be redirected back to the provided redirect url with an authorization code
- With this code, client id and client credentials, **webapp1** can obtain an access token from the **oauth server** and verify the user is logged in

So what to do now with this token? An app could pass it on every request as query param (not so good) or as authorization header (better) and extract it on each page load from the request and check against the **oauth server** if the user is still logged in.

This would create some heavy load on the **oauth** server, wouldn't it? So I would have to cache the token (and the expiration time) somehow and read the token from the cache and check if it is expiration time has not been reached.

Or I would save the token in a session and set the session lifetime according to the token expiration time ... ?

I'm a bit stuck at the moment. What could be the way to go?

Comment: OAuth 2.0 cannot be used to provide authentication/SSO, see: https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the link! But I wouldn't say it cannot be used but it should not be used (alone) in terms of security. I will have a look at OpenId.